# PHP Get Multi Select List Values

Tags: php, function, select-menu

I'm trying to write a simple function to construct field names for a form. It works fine if at least one value is selected in a multi-select list but if nothing is selected I get an Undefined index error. Here is what I have:

```
function mcFieldName($mcFieldName){
$mcField = $_POST[$mcFieldName];
if( !is_array($mcField) ){
    if( !empty($mcField) ){
        return $mcField;
    }else{
        return 'n/a';
    }
}
if( is_array($mcField) ){
    $mcFieldArray = implode(',', $mcField);
    return $mcFieldArray;
}
```

}

```
$MultiSelect = mcFieldName('mcMultiSelect');
// test
echo $MultiSelect . '<br/>';
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to protect yourself from reading a key that does not exist in `$_POST`:

```
$mcField = isset($_POST[$mcFieldName]) ? $_POST[$mcFieldName] : null;
```

Comment: I tried the isset and !empty but neither of them worked. I don't understand the null part.

Comment: @user1002039: What this does is set `$mcField` to the field's value if one was posted, or to `null` if one was not. Your existing code would then react to the `null` value by returning `"n/a"`. I 'm not sure what you mean "you tried and neither worked".

Answer (score 1):

Before you try to access an array item make sure it exists with using `isset()`:

```
if (isset($_POST[$mcFieldName])) {
    $mcField = $_POST[$mcFieldName];
    ...
}
```